trying to settle a debate: Is this a "yes or no" question
Trying to settle a debate here.
Usually people only put one of the options, affirmative or negative, in a yes or no question, like:
"Can I apply X process to Y?"
It may be redundant, cause the "or not" is implied anyway in the example above, but would including both outcomes anyway prevent it from still being a yes or no question?
ex: "Can I apply X process to Y, or not?"
If I asked you "Can I apply X process to Y, or not?", what would you have replied?
Cheers.

If I answered yes to "Can I apply X process to Y, or not?" what would you interpret that to mean?

In my experience, it depends entirely on the thought process of the person replying.  There was a time when I was in the habit of doing this.  I found that most people were answering the first part of the statement, but people originating from UK were replying to the second part.  It gets very confusing an it is best not to ask a question with both outcomes.

IMHO, only Boolean pedants would answer "yes" in a snarky way.

I wonder how those people were replying to the second part? However the question is asked, the answer surely is either "Yes, you can" or "No, you can't".

As Kate says. The semantically nonsensical (but often used for emphasis, testy or to show urgency) 'or not' (etc) renders a one-word answer ambiguous. But as Kate points out, the legitimate answers can only read 'yes you can' or 'no, you can't' (ignoring guarded replies like 'possibly' or 'I'm not sure'), not 'Peter' / 'an octopus' / 'half past three' / 'very carefully' /  'three or four dozen' / 'under the sink' / 'a yellowy-green' ....

The "or not" is more likely to be added when the person asking the question repeats it because they didn't get an unequivocal answer. "You didn't answer my question. Is there a company policy about taking off for religious holidays or not?"

If I asked "Can I apply X process to Y, or not?" I'd hope for an answer like "Yes, it'll be fine" or "No, not unless you..."

@Stuart Though even yes/no questions may legitimately be responded to by "I don't know," "Possibly," "Sometimes," "I think so" ... (hedging) or "Sometimes" ... (showing that the question is considered to allow a gradience of answers).
